# Django - Is My Static File in the Wrong Place?

Tags: javascript, django, django-static

I'm creating a project for a weather app with Django, and I think my Javascript file is in the wrong place. I have it in a static folder.
But I'm getting the console error GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/capstone/capstone.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Here is how my project files are set up. Is this correct?

In settings.py I also have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a new folder `capstone` and move your capstone.js to it.
cause by default Django uses a `static` folder within an app, so in your case, you're visiting http://localhost:8000/static/capstone/capstone.js but the actual link is http://localhost:8000/static/capstone.js

Answer (score 0):

Your `BASE_DIR` by default points to the same directory that `manage.py` is in. If you haven't changed it then `capstone.js` is currently located in

```py
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'capstone/static')
```

BUT django by default looks for a `static` folder inside each installed app so in your case `STATCFILES_DIRS` is redundant.

Make sure you have added the static files to your `urls.py`.

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

or

```py
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    # ...urls
]

# static content urls
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

This is my best guess as to why you are getting a 404 error.

NB: if you *have* setup static urls then try

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/capstone.js` instead.